# change the layout dynamically using frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

i am learning fragments and i am stuck in how to dynamically change layout in the main activity where i want to call different fragments according to the list text i choose from a listview.

This is the Fragment extension class. Do i have to do any if else here so that i can return my desired layout?Lets say i click another option in listview and i want Layout.arts instead of Layout.sports to be shown in the main activity, how can it be done?

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sports, container, false);
    }

}
```

here is the onclick listener for the listview

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Hello","Clicked");
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            MenuFragment frag = new MenuFragment();

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment, String.valueOf(position));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can open different fragments from different positions of list item click.

Answer (score 0):

If the business logic is same other than only layout, you can write the if - else condition in the `onCreateView()` of `Fragment`

If the business logic is different for sports and arts then create two different fragments for sports and arts and `onItemClick()` method replace the appropriate fragment.

Comment: how to choose between the fragments?

Comment: Can you elaborate wt u asking?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with Layout Inflater:

```
public void changeView(int layoutId){ 
    container.removeAllViewsInLayout(); 
    inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, true); 
}
```

container and inflater are from onCreateView.

Comment: Are you able to explain how to do it, or provide a working example?

Comment: <code>public void changeView(int layoutId){
 container.removeAllViewsInLayout();
 inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, true);
 }</code> container and inflater are from onCreateView